# Wrapping Text in a DataGrid Cell C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in C# that currently has a column where text can be entered and carriage returns accepted. This currently ends up in a lot of scenarios where this occurs;

[image]

What I would prefer is that the first 'Test' appears but the rest are hidden, i.e. the DataGrid row only takes up one row instead of expanding. I would then display the rest of the text in a `TextBox` below so the users can still see it.

How can I wrap the text so that each row does not expand? I have had a look at [MSDN DataGridView Wrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode(v=vs.110).aspx) but as this is WPF and not WinForms I am struggling to find examples for a `DataGrid` not a `DataGridView`

Comment: You can use RowHeight in your DataGrid to define the height of each row.

Comment: @Kami Fantastic , nice and simple! I don't spose you know the default height of a row do you?

Comment: I don't think there is a default height of a row, but I might be mistaken.